# Linear interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, missing-data

I am working with a dataset containing columns for GDP and GDP per capita for a number of countries. These columns contain missing values. Due to the nature of the data I was hoping to play around with linear interpolation in order to fill in the missing values without losing the general shape of the data.

My code looks as follows:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("Country")

#Iterate over the groups
   for country, group in grouped_df:

#Select the rows that contain missing values
    missing_values = group[group["GDP percapita"].isnull()]
    if not missing_values.empty:

#Interpolate to fill the missing values
        filled_values = missing_values["GDP percapita"].interpolate(method="linear")
#Update the original dataframe
        df.update(filled_values)
```

When I run this however, the missing values are still present in my dataset, however I can't find the issue with my code.

Comment: Try considering ffill or bfill , have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html or https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/what-is-ffill-and-bfill-pandas

Comment: Are these preferable to linear interpolation? It seems that that seems to be the most common solution for data with peaks and troughs such as financial data, whereas something line ffill or bfill might flatten the data?

Comment: you as user need to decided what interpolation suits your need , you can choose method of interpolation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate

Comment: I have updated my code to add this in and still no luck getting my above code to work! I'm thinking there's a syntax error I am not spotting?

Answer (score 0):

replace

> filled_values = missing_values["GDP
> percapita"].interpolate(method="linear")

with

> filled_values = group["GDP
> percapita"].interpolate(method="linear")

Here is little working sample

```
d= {"country": ["Brazil", "Brazil", "India", "India", ],
        "cities": ["Brasilia", "Rio", "New Dehli", "Bombay"],
        "population": [200.4, None, 100.10, None]}
p= pd.DataFrame(d)
print(p) #should give you

  country     cities  population
0  Brazil   Brasilia       200.4
1  Brazil        Rio         NaN
2   India  New Dehli       100.1
3   India     Bombay         NaN

# to interpolate entire df
p.interpolate(method='linear')

  country     cities  population
0  Brazil   Brasilia      200.40
1  Brazil        Rio      150.25
2   India  New Dehli      100.10
3   India     Bombay      100.10

#to interpolate group wise

grouped_df = p.groupby("country")
#Iterate over the groups
for country, group in grouped_df:
    missing_values = group[group["population"].isnull()]
    filled_values = 
    missing_values["population"].interpolate(method="linear")
    p.update(filled_values)
```

Comment: As reason seems simple , interpolation from missing values will be another missing values

Comment: This is on the right track, however you are definitely right in that a majority of my missing values are adjacent to other missing values so this method is not working. I may have to figure out another way to deal with this if there is no workaround?